# Why won't my images not load in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-glide, android-image

**Glide** won't load the images I have linked with the products on my `RecyclerView`. The images should be pulled from my PHP MySQL database. Not really sure what I did wrong. Please help

I've tried a few solutions I found on the web but none of them worked for me.

```
private String image;
```

The above is the string identifier from my product list

```
 //loading the image
    Glide.with(mCtx)
            .load(product.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.textViewPlateNumber.setText(product.getPlatenumber());
    holder.textView1.setText(product.getMake());
    holder.textView2.setText(product.getModel());
    holder.textView3.setText(product.getYear());
    holder.textViewName.setText(product.getName());
    holder.textDate.setText(product.getDate());

    holder.recyclerid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String platenumber = productList.get(position).getPlatenumber();
            String make = productList.get(position).getMake();
            String model = productList.get(position).getModel();
            String year = productList.get(position).getYear();
            String name = productList.get(position).getName();
            String date = productList.get(position).getDate();
            String vin = productList.get(position).getVin();
            String displacement = productList.get(position).getDisplacement();
            String fueltype = productList.get(position).getFueltype();
            String transmission = productList.get(position).getTransmission();
            String mileage = productList.get(position).getMileage();
            String ownerorcompany = 
     productList.get(position).getOwnerorcompany();
            String homeorcompanyaddress = 
  productList.get(position).getHomeorcompanyaddress();
            String contactnumber = 
 productList.get(position).getContactnumber();
             String emailaddress = productList.get(position).getEmailaddress();
            String facebook = productList.get(position).getFacebook();
            String image = productList.get(position).getImage();
```

The above is the code I used to show the images of each item off my adapter.

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/car_avatar"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/cta"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline17"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The above is how the image should be laid out in my xml file. The rest of the items saved on my `php` `sql` show up on the list except the images. Here is what my `php` file looks like:

```
$vehicle = array(); 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
 $temp = array();



 $temp['id'] = $row['VehicleID']; 
 $temp['platenumber'] = $row['PlateNumber']; 
 $temp['make'] = $row['Make']; 
 $temp['model'] = $row['Model']; 
 $temp['year'] = $row['Year']; 
 $temp['name'] = $row['OwnerorCompany']; 
 $temp['date'] = $row['AddDate']; 
 $temp['image'] = $row['vehicleImage'];
 $temp['vin'] = $row['Vin'];
 $temp['displacement'] = $row['Displacement']; 
 $temp['fueltype'] = $row['FuelType'];
 $temp['transmission'] = $row['Transmission'];
 $temp['mileage'] = $row['Mileage'];
 $temp['ownerorcompany'] = $row['OwnerorCompany'];
 $temp['homeorcompanyaddress'] = $row['HomeorCompanyAddress'];
 $temp['contactnumber'] = $row['ContactNumber'];
 $temp['emailaddress'] = $row['EmailAddress'];
 $temp['facebook'] = $row['FacebookID'];

 array_push($vehicle, $temp);


 }
 echo json_encode($vehicle);
 //}
 ?>
```

And this is how the images are saved on my database:

```
    $photo = $_POST['photo'];

    $id=uniqid();

    $path = "vehicle_upload/$id.jpeg";
    $finalpath = "http://192.168.0.10/widevalueautoInc 
    2/server/api/".$path;
```

When I run the app, all goes well except the images not showing up on the list. This is the java code I used to save the image and the size.

```
 private void addVehicle(String stringImage) {
 }

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] imageByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, 
 Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
}
```

Comment: do two things. 1: put your adapter code in the question. 2: see the list values that it is containing the image path?

Comment: @WendellDaguno, Did you check the `image URL` on a browser?

Comment: @RakeshKumar - yes i did and the images work well. In fact when I save them, they go to the correct folder.

Comment: @WendellDaguno, It seems your image too big and that could cause the taking delay to load on the place holder. Try to resize the image on Glide may work for you.

Comment: @RakeshKumar I posted the java code I used to save the images in the server.

Comment: @WendellDaguno, Did you check this `product.getImage()`???

Comment: @RakeshKumar I had this if this was what you meant...public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

Comment: @WendellDaguno, I was meant to say that value or data of `product.getImage()` have printed or `Log`?

Comment: maybe this is issue with circular image view try using default Image view just to verify if the url is fine then this could be the issue.

Comment: @WendellDaguno can you post the image URL which is not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove circular imageview and use default image view, to use circle crop .. use Glide circle crop function....

```
Glide.with(context).load("dddd").apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(imageview);
```

Comment: This pretty much did the job! That you very much to all that took time to help me out. Appreciate it big time!

Comment: @WendellDaguno if your problem is sloved ,then you can click on tick to green on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a common method as below in your utility class as below :

```
public static void setCircularImageToGlide(final Context context, final CircularImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
        Glide.with(context).load("" + imageUrl).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder).transform(new CircleTransform(context)).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have passed `CircularImageView` as an argument to method single you are using `CircularImageView` instead of simple `ImageView`.

Call it as below wherever you need to set image in to your `CircularImageView` as below :

```
CommonUtil.setCircularImageToGlide(YOUR_CONTEXT, YOUR_CIRCULAR_IMAGE_VIEW, "" + YOUR_IMAGE_URL);
```

Am using below dependency :

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```